# Embed Inkscape SVG as svg+xml to change color via CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, inkscape

I created this SVG Icon with Inkscape:
https://codepen.io/honk007/pen/Jjoeryp

I managed to embed simpler Icons directly into HTML so i could change colors via CSS like this:

```
.mydiv > circle {
    fill: #f00;
}
```

I tried to embed this Icon in all possible ways but its not displaying. I could embed it in base64 but then I can't change colors and I would like to change the `fill: #5b4cdf;` color dynamically.

When embeding via JS like this:

```
const svg_O = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 29"><defs><filter id="a" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFlood flood-opacity=".5" flood-color="#000"/><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in"/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/><feOffset/><feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/></filter></defs><path d="M22 12.4a10 10 0 01-6.2 9.3c-1.2.4-3.2 3.8-3.8 4.8-.7-1-2.6-4.3-3.8-4.8A10 10 0 1122 12.4z" fill="#efefef" filter="url(#a)"/><circle cx="12" cy="12.4" r="7" fill="#5b4cdf"/><path d="M14.5 12.2h1L12 9l-3.5 3.2h1V15h1.8v-2.1h1.4V15h1.8z" fill="#fff"/></svg>';  
const svgpin_O = encodeURI("data:image/svg+xml;utf-8," + svg_O).replace('#', '%23');

const icon_O = L.icon({
        iconUrl: svgpin_O,
        iconSize: [90, 101],
        iconAnchor: [45, 0]
    });
```

I get this:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox=%220%200%2024%2029%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cfilter%20id=%22a%22%20color-interpolation-filters=%22sRGB%22%3E%3CfeFlood%20flood-opacity=%22.5%22%20flood-color=%22%23000%22/%3E%3CfeComposite%20in2=%22SourceGraphic%22%20operator=%22in%22/%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur%20stdDeviation=%221%22/%3E%3CfeOffset/%3E%3CfeComposite%20in=%22SourceGraphic%22/%3E%3C/filter%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cpath%20d=%22M22%2012.4a10%2010%200%2001-6.2%209.3c-1.2.4-3.2%203.8-3.8%204.8-.7-1-2.6-4.3-3.8-4.8A10%2010%200%201122%2012.4z%22%20fill=%22#efefef%22%20filter=%22url(#a)%22/%3E%3Ccircle%20cx=%2212%22%20cy=%2212.4%22%20r=%227%22%20fill=%22#5b4cdf%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d=%22M14.5%2012.2h1L12%209l-3.5%203.2h1V15h1.8v-2.1h1.4V15h1.8z%22%20fill=%22#fff%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E">
```

And that is not displaying the icon inside a browser.

Is there a way to embed this Icon in a way to change the circle color dynamically via CSS?

Comment: Some parts of this article will help you https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: Nothing new. Have a solution?

Comment: I don't know a way to do that yet

Comment: Like i said I did it already with less complex structures.

Comment: I am not sure i understand well your question what i understand at the moment is that you want to embed the svg like an image instead of copy pasting all that code, and still be able to change colors of svg circles right?

Answer (score 1):

You can change any SVG color using only one parent div class.

Check you update snippet is here:    https://codepen.io/hardiksolanki/pen/eYmQepM

```
.svg_icon svg circle{
  fill: #f00 !important;
}
```

Comment: I know that, but i need to embed that icon into HTML. Problem occurs, when trying to embed. I will extend my question for this.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it based on this:

```
var iconSettings = {
        mapIconUrl: '<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 149 178"><path fill="{mapIconColor}" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M126 23l-6-6A69 69 0 0 0 74 1a69 69 0 0 0-51 22A70 70 0 0 0 1 74c0 21 7 38 22 52l43 47c6 6 11 6 16 0l48-51c12-13 18-29 18-48 0-20-8-37-22-51z"/><circle fill="{mapIconColorInnerCircle}" cx="74" cy="75" r="61"/><circle fill="#FFF" cx="74" cy="75" r="{pinInnerCircleRadius}"/></svg>',
        mapIconColor: 'blue',
        mapIconColorInnerCircle: '#fff',
        pinInnerCircleRadius:48
    };


// icon normal state
var divIcon = L.divIcon({
    className: "leaflet-data-marker",
  html: L.Util.template(iconSettings.mapIconUrl, iconSettings), //.replace('#','%23'),
  iconAnchor  : [12, 32],
  iconSize    : [25, 30],
  popupAnchor : [0, -28]
});
```

https://codepen.io/honk007/pen/WNbYXad